# Playframework test-runner selenium permission denied Location.href and Command Execution Failure

Tags: permissions, selenium, playframework, test-runner

This test works locally, but when run from the Play test runner on our aws ci instance, I get the following permissions error in Firefox: Permission denied for HOST to get property Location.href and then Command execution error.
[image]

In Chrome, the remote message is different, but I sense the same underlying reason. Object <> has no method 'getCurrentWindow'.

[image]

Is it this issue? http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=703

Answer (score 0):

you are using the Play standard test runner from a remote location, which is the source of the issue (as far as I know).

Try to use **play auto-test** as described [here](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.1.1/test#continuous) to run the tests.

Comment: The test fails remotely but passes locally when using auto-test too. The only reason I did it with the test runner is because it failed when going through our automated CI process, which runs play auto-test for every new build. I wanted to see detailed output and why it failed, which wasn't in the auto-test output. Thanks!